# Why do rx-let definitions not work inside of pcase?

Tags: rx, pcase

I am using pattern matching in Emacs Lisp with `pcase`. I would like to simplify the `rx` expressions I am using by binding common pattern with rx-let. However, it seems like if you use `rx` by itself the substitution works as expected. However, if `rx` is within `pcase`, the identifier cannot be resolved.

I would expect the following code to return `t`:

```
(rx-let ((custom-value "a"))
  (pcase "a" ((rx custom-value) t)))
```

However, this instead results in an error stating "Unknown rx symbol `custom-value`".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's [bug#59814](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=59814) which is fixed in Emacs 29.